# Selecting and zooming in on features from standalone PyQGIS script?

Tags: pyqgis, zoom

I want to select and zoom in features in active QGIS project from external application.

This script do all the things I need, except it does not affect currently running project. It selects and makes zoom to selected but not in opened QGIS project. It shows standalone python window instead of project's.

If I remove last command - `qgis.exec_()` I see only empty console window - no changes in running project's window.

```
# coding=UTF-8
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas,QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
import os.path

qgis = QgsApplication([], True)
qgis.initQgis()

project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
if project.fileName() == "":
    my_file = os.path.isfile(os.path.join('c:\qgis_test','test.qgs'))
    if my_file:
      project.read(QFileInfo(os.path.join('c:\qgis_test','test.qgs')))

bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(project.layerTreeRoot(), canvas, qgis)
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
expr = QgsExpression( "\"name\"='{}'".format('Gothenburg'))

selLayer = layers.items()[0][1]

it = selLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [i.id() for i in it]
selLayer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
box = selLayer.boundingBoxOfSelected()

canvas.setExtent(box)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.zoomToFeatureIds(selLayer,ids)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.show()
qgis.exec_()
```

I think I need to create link between QgsApplication in script and currently running project window but don't know how to do it.

Comment: To clarify, you want reference from a standalone script to an already open QGIS project?

Comment: Yes, I want to do all the things in currently opened project.